# How to make python return as many riddles as I want from a list

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner and want to create a simple riddles game, but I want that the user could select how many riddles he wants. Right now I tried to use 'for' function but I think I messed it up, any tips?
my current code:

```
import random

random_riddle_list = ('If an airplane crashed exactly on the border of the United States and Canada, where would the survivors be buried?'  ,
                      'What does an orange do when it takes a rest? ' , 'A cowboy rides in a town on Friday stays for three days and leaves on Friday. How is that possible? ' ,
                      'What disappears the instant you say its name? ' , 'Which berry makes a harsh noise? ' , 'How do you tell a boy snowman apart from a girl snowman? ' ,
                      'You walk a mile south, a mile east and then a mile north. You end up in exact same spot you started. Where are you? ' , 'What connects two people but touches only one? ')
riddle_number = str(len(random_riddle_list))
riddles_wanted = str(input("How many riddles do you want?(max 8): "))
for riddle_number in riddles_wanted:
    random_riddle = random.choice(random_riddle_list)
    answer = input(random_riddle).lower()
    if answer == "You don’t bury survivors":
        print("Correct")
    elif answer == "Concentrates":
            print("Correct")
    elif answer == "His horse is named Friday":
        print("Correct")
    elif answer == "Silence":
        print("Correct")
    elif answer == "Raspberry":
        print("Correct")
    elif answer =="Snowballs":
        print("Correct")
    elif answer =="The North Pole":
        print("Correct")
    elif answer =="A wedding ring":
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Comment: ```random_riddle_list``` is actually a tuple due to the ```(``` instead of ```[```

Comment: You read through the `random` documentation to find the method that returns a list of items drawn from a population: `sample`.  Where did you get stuck with that?

Comment: You aren't checking if the answer is the correct answer for the `random_riddle`. I could give *any* of the answers for *any* riddle and your program would print "Correct". You should probably use a `dict` to store the `{riddle: answer}` pairs. Also cast `riddles_wanted` before looping: `for riddle_number in range(int(riddles_wanted)):`

Comment: yeah I know, I just started learning today programming so that's why the code is shit, thanks @not_speshal I will try it

Comment: wait it worked, lettts gooooo, thanks

Comment: @not_speshal 1 more question, how could I make so the random riddles don't repeat themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Matthew! You can find a suggestion below.

Creating a list of riddle answers will allow you to reduce verbosity during the answer checking portion of your code. Also I suggest the use of `random.sample` to replace `random.choice` so you don't get repeated riddles.

```
import random

random_riddle_list = ['If an airplane crashed exactly on the border of the United States and Canada, where would the survivors be buried?'  ,
                      'What does an orange do when it takes a rest? ' , 'A cowboy rides in a town on Friday stays for three days and leaves on Friday. How is that possible? ' ,
                      'What disappears the instant you say its name? ' , 'Which berry makes a harsh noise? ' , 'How do you tell a boy snowman apart from a girl snowman? ' ,
                      'You walk a mile south, a mile east and then a mile north. You end up in exact same spot you started. Where are you? ' , 'What connects two people but touches only one? ']

riddle_answers = ["You don’t bury survivors", "His horse is named Friday", "Silence", "Raspberry", "Snowballs", "The North Pole", "A wedding ring"]

riddles_wanted = int(input("How many riddles do you want?(max 8): "))
random_riddles_numbers = random.sample(population = range(len(random_riddle_list)),k=riddles_wanted)

for n in random_riddles_numbers:
    answer = input(random_riddle_list[n]).lower()
    if answer == riddle_answers[n].lower():
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: lol well, this is a lil too advance for me to understand with that population and k= but will try to find info on that. Thank u very much

Comment: Oh one more question, what is the [n]? like the for n or riddle_answers [n]? I know its probably a stupid question but as I said I only started learning today

Comment: population is the list from which you want to choose elements and k is the number of samples you want. n is just the position of the riddle in the list. so when you want to grab the nth member in the list you do list[n]. Important to notice that the position count starts at 0.

Comment: bro ur a lifesaver thank you very muchhhhh

Comment: for some reason it says: if answer == riddle_answers[n].lower()
 IndexError: list index out of range
what does it mean?

Comment: letts goo found the problem, it was just that there was one answer lacking, professional coder now basically lol/s

Comment: awesome! you will get there in no time.

Comment: Just tried the whole function and for some reason, It shows that all riddles are incorrect even when I write the right answer. Thats strange my code is the same as u put in the answer tho

Comment: one answer was missing from the list. `riddle_answers = ["You don’t bury survivors",  "Concentrates, "His horse is named Friday", "Silence", "Raspberry", "Snowballs", "The North Pole", "A wedding ring"]`